# How do I determine by Apex code if Custom Field allows setting Field Level Security and if can be edited?

Tags: custom-field, fields, field-level-security, fls, system-fields

To assign correct FLS permissions in bulk for a given profile I need to know which fields are readonly and which fields support Field Level Security.
I see that there is field `IsFlsEnabled` in `FieldDefinition` standard object, but it is not supported when I try to make SOQL.

Despite field `IsFlsEnabled` is present in documentation of [`FieldDefinition` standard object](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_fielddefinition.htm), I received an error when I try to execute an SOQL in Apex code like

```
select Label, IsCalculated from FieldDefinition where IsFlsEnabled = True
```

> No such column 'IsFlsEnabled' on entity 'FieldDefinition'. If you are
> attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after
> the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call
> for the appropriate names.

How do I overcome this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[There is difference in fields available in Tooling API and SOQL, not every field from Tooling API is available for SOQL](https://patlatus.wordpress.com/2018/08/17/determine-by-apex-if-custom-field-allows-setting-field-level-security/).

However, for Field Level Security it is easy to mitigate this problem by relying on two other fields which are available in SOQL like `PublisherId` and `IsNillable`.

Every field, which is not required and which is not system field, supports Field Level Security.

Also every field, which is not calculated, supports Edit permission.

So instead of querying for field `IsFlsEnabled`

```
select Label, IsCalculated from FieldDefinition where IsFlsEnabled = True
```

it is possible to query for `PublisherId` and `IsNillable`

```
select Label, IsCalculated from FieldDefinition where IsNillable = True AND PublisherId != 'System'
```

Also, if `IsCalculated` is true then field doesn't support Edit permission. If it is false then field supports Edit permission.

Answer (score 0):

I am considering contact's email field before querying this field. I am checking `isAccessible` for the email field. Please see the below example.

```
if (Schema.sObjectType.Contact.fields.Email.isAccessible()) {
   Contact c = [SELECT Email FROM Contact WHERE Id= :Id];
}
```